# Elasticsearch split word on character to make query

Tags: elasticsearch, split, tokenize

I have some doc contains a word like

```
{ doc : 
"_id" : "A21_A25_A59",
...
}
```

When I make a query like A25 i don't get the doc.

I think i have to make a mappings with an analyzer to spit on '_' character

but I am not specialy famillear with it..

I have already a tokenizer like

```
"path_tokenizer" : {
            "delimiter" : "/",
            "type" : "path_hierarchy"
         }
```

if i do one like

```
"path_tokenizer" : {
            "delimiter" : "_",
            "type" : "separate_word"
         }
```

that will work ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom filter to replace the character _ with space. In the example it replaces few other special characters as well along with underscore.

Follow this link.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html

Eg:

```
"char_filter": {
  "my_pattern": {
    "type": "pattern_replace",
    "pattern": "(_[-()',])",
    "replacement": " "
  },
  "my_mapping": {
    "type": "mapping",
    "mappings_path": "/etc/elasticsearch/replace_words.txt"
  }
}
```